# Can the attacker view the response from a CSRF attack request?

Tags: web-application, csrf

In CSRF attacks, the attacker crafts a specific request and convinces the victim to visit the page.

I have a doubt in one scenario. Suppose if the victim visits the page, and clicks on the button, there is a certain information disclosure like password etc. But the response is visible only in the victim's context.

Is there any way such that the attacker can view the response generated when the victim clicks on the button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CSRF attacks steal log in information?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112149), [Is it possible to read the response of HTTP request without XHR?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166676), [Is data exposed in a CSRF attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/).

Comment: Visibility is irrelevant. The click can trigger anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way such that the attacker can view the response generated when the victim clicks on the button?

No, not in a pure CSRF attack. The direct effect of a CSRF attack is not information disclosure. It is tricking the server to perform some action. Examples of CSRF attacks would be:

- Delete a post by directing a CSRF attack at `example.com/posts/delete.php`.
- Changing the victims email to the attackers by tricking the victims browser to send a POST request to `example.com/user/update.php`.
- And so on...

The thing here is that the attacker doesn't need to read the response. As long as the server deletes the post or changes the email or whatever the attacker wins. A side effect of that could be some kind of information disclosure, but that is not the primary effect.

On a side note, the attacker doesn't have to trick the victim into clicking a button on the attackers page. All she has to do is trick the victim into visiting the page, the rest can be done automatically in the background with javascript.